# .NET Database polling and broadcasting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, notifications, broadcast, polling

I'm developing an application and need to send some real-time updates to users logged in. I'm currently developing for an XRM system which only offers email notifications, so to get things up and running a bit quicker I'm going to resort to polling the database.

I want to start a new process in the Application_Start() method in global.asax that will poll the database and broadcast among clients. The problem is I'm a bit of a noob and don't know what I need to get started.

I've read http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx and am aware of the potential flaws, as I said it's nothing more that getting it running first.

Could anyone tell me what kind of project I need to add to my solution? I was also thinking that it might work out a bit better if it runs async allowing me to poll different entities for updates simultaneously.

The polling is going to be regulated by the server, clients don't request for the poll so no long-polling with the database, the updates get pushed to the users subscribed to a groups. This will help me keep the polling minimal and also turn the polling off if no one is logged in.